# How to remove '/home' directory?

Tags: filesystem, symlink

OS X 10.9.5.

I have a `/home` directory in my filesystem. I want to remove it and create a symlink named `/home` pointing to `/Users` to make symlinks from GNU/Linux usable. But I cannot remove `/home` directory (`rmdir: home: Resource busy`) nor create any file under `/home` (`Operation not supported`).

Any solution?

Edit:
As @thomasjones pointed, there's really something mounted at `/home`. But what is that `map auto_home`?

```
$ df
Filesystem    512-blocks      Used Available Capacity  iused   ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2   624470624 579889472  44069152    93% 72550182 5508644   93%   /
devfs                371       371         0   100%      643       0  100%   /dev
map -hosts             0         0         0   100%        0       0  100%   /net
map auto_home          0         0         0   100%        0       0  100%   /home
```

Comment: Are you sure that /home isn't a partition?

Comment: @ThomasJones `map auto_home` is mounted at `/home`. But what is `map auto_home`?

Comment: It's a directory services NFS mount for reasons I don't know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open the following files with read/write permissions:

```
/etc/auto_home
/etc/auto_master
```

These files are part of the autofs installation.

In the `auto_home` file, add a # before the + on the following line:

> +auto_home # Use directory service

In the `auto_master` file, add a # before the /home on the following line:

> /home          auto_home   -nobrowse,hidefromfinder

Save both files, and reboot your computer. `/home` should be free to work with.

To reverse the changes, undo what you've done to both `auto_master` and `auto_home`.